# How do I extend the range of element so as to allow onmouseout trigger later

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML div where a mouse over will trigger a toolbar to pop up on the bottom left corner of the div. I want to add buttons to the div but I realise that the mouseout html attribute does not consider the toolbar as part of the div. As such the toolbar will be removed the moment i mouse over the toolbar. Is there any way to keep the toolbar there when i mouse over it?

```js
function glowRow(row){
    row.classList.add('mm-glow')
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('toolbar')
    row.appendChild(div)
}

function deactivateGlowRow(row){
    row.classList.remove('mm-glow')
    $(row).children().remove()
}
```

```css
.mm-glow {
  border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #86b7fe;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(13 110 253 / 75%);
  z-index: 1;
  position:relative;
}

.row {
  height: 250px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:red;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: rgb(13 110 253 / 75%);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 250px;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mm-align-top" onmouseover="glowRow(this)" onmouseout="deactivateGlowRow(this)">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mouseout` fires as soon as the cursor moves from the element onto a child element.

Use the `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` events instead.

```js
function glowRow(row){
    row.classList.add('mm-glow')
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('toolbar')
    row.appendChild(div)
}

function deactivateGlowRow(row){
    row.classList.remove('mm-glow')
    $(row).children().remove()
}
```

```css
.mm-glow {
  border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #86b7fe;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(13 110 253 / 75%);
  z-index: 1;
  position:relative;
}

.row {
  height: 250px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:red;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: rgb(13 110 253 / 75%);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 250px;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mm-align-top" onmouseenter="glowRow(this)" onmouseleave="deactivateGlowRow(this)">
            </div>
```